# Change default open/save dialog window folder FROM My Computer TO My Documents

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, file-management

How do I change the open/save file dialog window to use the My Documents ("User Files") by default on the left panel instead of adding an alias (that I've removed!) under My Computer? I already have *half* of the answer.

[image: File Open/Save Dialog window]

The command (Run command) I want to use is the following:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:UsersFilesFolder\Pictures
```

Where in the registry do I use this to overwrite the existing preference?

Comment: How are you launching the dialog(s)? Many applications save the last location that was accessed. There is no one "master" default.

Comment: @KeithMiller This was Waterfox however I'm more than willing to go through the registry and update per program. I create registry tweak files to fix stuff if I need to create a new user or reinstall Windows to avoid having to repeat the research and implementation. I've done some searches with shell commands though haven't been able to pinpoint it out.